# Inequality in $L^2$ based norms

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, partial-differential-equations

Recently I came across the following inequality. Let $f:\,\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be smooth, then the inequality $$\left\lVert f\right\lVert_{\dot H^2(\mathbb{R}^n)}\leq\left\lVert\Delta f\right\lVert_{L^2(\mathbb{R}^n)}$$ holds, where $\dot H^2(\mathbb R^n)$ denotes the homogeneous Sobolev norm on $\mathbb R^n$.

I tried to prove this brute-force, but I did not see where this was going. Is there an elegant and quick way of obtaining the estimate?

Comment: Could you add details on what didn't work? It seems to me that you can use the definition of those norms with Fourier transform.

Comment: is your homogeneous Sobolev norm $||f||^2 = \int_\mathbb{R^n} |\triangledown f(x)|^2 dx$?

Comment: Yes, I just tried to expand this expression and then compare my terms with the right hand side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$
\|D^2 v \|_2^2 = \int \sum_{i,j=1}^N v_{x_ix_j} v_{x_i x_j} = - \int \sum_{i,j=1}^N v_{x_i x_j x_i} v_{x_j} = \int \sum_{i=1}^N v_{x_i x_i} \sum_{j=1}^N v_{x_j x_j} = \|\Delta v\|_2^2
$$
for every $v \in C_0^3(\mathbb{R}^N)$. If you use Fourier analysis to define homogeneous Sobolev spaces, then the proof is even easier. The identity might become an inequality because people may use equivalent Sobolev constants.